# My circular array only gives 2 objects instead of my count

Tags: modifiers

Trying to do a circular array in Blender 2.8 as shown in many video's on Youtube. Except I don't get my desired count (5) but I only get two.
What I did:

- Placed my model off center
- Placed my origin in the center of the world
- Added an Empty in center of world (Cube, Axis, or whatever)
- Added Array modifier to my model
- Set next properties (Fixed Count, 5, Checked Offset and set to empty, unchecked Relative offset)
- Gave my empty a spin on the Z axis for 72° (360/5)

Any idea what I am missing here?
I must have done something wrong, I'm trying to do this for several attempts already but can't get it to work.

many many thanks for your assistance

Comment: It must have something to do with my model. Because when I use a simple circle or cube I can get it to work. I'm not sure because I have no other modifiers that aren't applied. I had a mirror which has been applied.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! As you already said, it might be because of your model. Yet we do not know what your model looks like, so finding an answer is pretty hard. Could you please [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/145258/edit) your post and add e.g. a picture?

Comment: Applied scale and rotation for object in question?